# Windows CE apps update to Windows Mobile or switch to another platform?

Tags: c#, android, windows-mobile, windows-ce

This may not be exactly a programming question, but it's about platform and programming languages and I've been asked to advice on it.

Consider a few apps for Windows CE made a few years ago. No local storage needed, no web service calls, just plain IP to IP communication and data being send in real time.

I want to ask you, what would be the real alternatives to switch to a more modern and supported platform?

1. How hard is it for an Windows CE app to be converted to the newest Windows Mobile platform? Can it go like a rebuild or there are a lot of changes needed?
2. Is it better to switch to a new platform, like android?
3. Would it be a better alternative to use a hybrid app which would work on both Android and Windows Phone? considering that there is some knowledge of C#

Thank you

Comment: I would expect any proper response to this question to be very opinion based.

Comment: That is a huge topic you bring to speech here. You have to google and read about it. What do you mean with switching from CE to Windows Mobile? Which windows mobile do you mean? CE and Windows Mobile can run the same software it is developed with Visual Studio 2008. What VS-Version do you have? Also it would be good to know which devices you currently have: Is it a mobile barcode scanner or something else? Not every manufacturer has "good" android devices at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app have a simple UI, you could consider the possibility of doing it cross-platform through Xamarin.Forms, since you have C# skills.